# Django 2.0 : Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: auth

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication, django-allauth

I've got this error after I tried to migrate my files

PS C:\djangoproject\src> python manage.py makemigrations

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",line 371, in 
execute_from_command_line utility.execute()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py",line 347, in execute
     django.setup()   
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)   
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 93, in populate
        "duplicates: %s" % app_config.label)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: auth
```

Please help.

Comment: looks like you custom auth app. just give it another name

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'profiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',

    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
]

Comment: from django.apps import AppConfig


class ProfilesConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'profiles'
    verbose_name = 'myprofile'

Comment: default_app_config = 'profiles.apps.ProfilesConfig'

Comment: urlpatterns = [
 path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', allauth.urls),

]

Answer (score 16):

You have an extra `'django.contrib.auth'`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ 'django.contrib.admin', 
               'django.contrib.auth', 
               'django.contrib.contenttypes', 
               'django.contrib.sessions', 
               'django.contrib.messages', 
               'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
               'profiles', 
               'crispy_forms', 
               'django.contrib.auth',     --->EXTRA Remove this
               'django.contrib.sites', 
               'allauth', 
               'allauth.account'
 ]
```

Comment: urlpatterns = [
 path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

]

Comment: File "C:\djangoproject\src\testsite\urls.py", line 28, in <module>
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
NameError: name 'include' is not defined

Comment: urlpatterns = [
 path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', allauth.urls),

]

Comment: File "C:\djangoproject\src\testsite\urls.py", line 28, in <module>
    path('accounts/', allauth.urls),
NameError: name 'allauth' is not defined

Comment: @seven7hell , edit your code with your current issues, so we can help you, stop doing it in comments

Comment: @Lemayzeur I got my solution. Thanks for the advice. I will keep this in mind next time